# How to add an additional value to a input box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to edit a custom php/JS script input box so a custom suffix is sent with a user inputted value. But so far I haven't managed to succeed.

I need to add ",UK" onto the address variable.

I have tried this

```
var address = search_form['address'].value + ",UK",
```

But no luck.

```
getCurrentLocations: function()
{
    var self = this,
    search_form = document.forms[self.opts.search_form_name],
    address = search_form['address'].value,
    radius = search_form['radius'].value;
```

I'm just not seeing the address var attaching ",UK"

Comment: i think u can just append the value in your field. isnt it?

Comment: did you tried the solution? read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need?

```
search_form['address'].value = search_form['address'].value + ", UK";
```

Comment: It's not a trick mate :) you were properly assigning the value to "some variable", but not putting it back to the input field.

Comment: yes agreed its better to store value in a variable then you can append @NickRider

Comment: @devpro ... is it?

Comment: I understand what your saying @devpro but I don't need to do anything with the variable but send it once in my situation. If I wanted to call it or save it for use later then storing it would be required and make more sense.

Comment: yes if you need to use at once then you can overwrite the value... storing in a variable will keep the original value save @NickRider

Answer (score 0):

You need to store old value before appending, then you can create new value in new variable like:

```
var old_address = search_form['address'].value;
var new_address = old_address + ", UK";
```

You can also append by using addition assignment operator `+=` like:

```
var address = search_form['address'].value;
address += ", UK";
```

**Working Example 1:**

```js
var address = "Mike Address";
address += ", UK ";
console.log(address);
```

**Working Example 2:**

```js
var address = "Mike Address";
var new_address = address+", UK ";
console.log(new_address);
```